# How do you transfer videos to iTunes/iPod?

Tags: video, itunes

I have a load of videos from my old Walkman that I transferred to my new computer, and want to put them on to the iPod I bought as a replacement MP3 device.

When I press the "Add File/Folder to Library" and select one of these videos, nothing happens, and they don't show up in any folder, and can't be found on the iPod once synced.

How do I do put the videos on my iPod?

Comment: You need to convert the videos to some format the iPod can read. Handbrake will do  this.

Comment: Thanks @slhck   I've downloaded Handbrake, but in the Destination File, it only accepts .mp4 files, which is what I'm trying to convert to, not from.

Comment: OK, figured out that Destination is not what I thought, but it still doesn't work. I can't click Save where I want it to be saved, and the help wiki on handbrake's site is useless.

Comment: You have to open the videos you want to convert with *Source* (or *File » Open Source…* on my Mac), and the *Destination* field is where they will be converted to. Then, just select an iPod device profile for the encoding settings.

Comment: What model is the Walkman? What format are the videos? They might be already be MP4/AVC, but if they are not showing up, it might be because they are in WMV format [\[1\]](http://www.sony.co.in/productcategory/walkman-mp3-player#b1) [\[2\]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkman#Walkman_Video_MP3_Player) [\[3\]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_NW-A810#Differences_with_Sony_Walkman_NW-A800).